# Defining Bessel functions $J_{v}(x)$ for real positive variable $x$?

Tags: electrostatics, mathematics, special-functions

I've been reading Zangwill's book. The topic of laplace equation in cylindrical coordinates. He proposes defining $J_{v}(x)$ only for $x\geq 0$. He defines it like that but I wonder if there's a consequence or justification. I think it may have to do with the fact of converting them as a complete set of orthogonal functions.

Comment: What is $x$ mean in cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: I forgot, In this case $x=kp$, $p$ is the variable radius

Comment: Okay, so can radius be negative?

Comment: but k can be any real

Comment: Are you sure? I'd still assume $k\geq0$ because allowing $k<0$ would mean you have a negative radius as a coordinate point.

Comment: yeah, but I meant about the consequences. He then is forced to write always $J_{v}(sx)$ , $s$ is the absolute value of $k$. I mean does it make a difference setting up $x>o$ because in general k it's not restricted.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 0):

I think that is due to the fact that you are looking for a solution that preserves a certain degree of symmetry. Let us consider for example the problem $$\Delta u =0$$, with suitable boundary conditions. If you change coordinates passing to a cyclindrical reference frame, you are using the following change of variables:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}&\to [0,+\infty)\times [0,2\pi)\times \mathbb{R}\\
(x,y,z)&\mapsto (\rho, \theta, z)  
\end{align}$$

where $\rho$ denotes the radial distance and is positively defined.

That's why you're only looking for $x\geq0$